# ng-fullcalendar - Angular 6 - external events in ngFor loop

Tags: angular, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I try to use "drag and drop" function with external events.

It works except if I use *ngFor :

My HTML file :

```
<p>Interventions en attente</p>
<ul id='external-events'>
     <li *ngFor="let ticket of ticketList">
        <div class='fc-event'>{{ ticket.message }}</div>  // Doesn't Work !!
     </li>
     <li>
         <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>  // Works !!
     </li>
</ul>
```

Here my TS file :

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function () {
        // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
        $(this).data('event', {
            title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
            stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
        });
        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        });

    });
}
```

How can I solve that ?

****************  UPDATE 2  ***********************

Here is my new getTickets method by following advices in comment :

```
 getNewTickets() {
    this.loading = false;
    this.myJarviaServices.getNewTickets()
        .subscribe(resp => {
                console.log('angular');
            this.ticketList = resp.content;
            console.log(this.ticketList);
                this.customevents.forEach(function (item) {
                    // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
                    $(item.nativeElement).data('event', {
                        title: $.trim($(item.nativeElement).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                        stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
                    });
                    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
                    $(item.nativeElement).draggable({
                        zIndex: 999,
                        revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                        revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
                    });

                });
        },
        error => {
            console.log('authService.login error' + error);
            console.log('error status : ' + error.status);
            // this.alertService.error(error);
            this.myJarviaServices.error(error);
        });
}
```

I have no error message but it doesn't work

Comment: can you provide an example in stackblitz?

Comment: this is quite likely to happen if the jQuery code runs before the ng-for Angular code. In that case, the jQuery code will not find any events to loop over, because they haven't been created yet. I don't know Angular at all, so I don't know if that's the case, but you can easily verify it - simply use the debugger to see if your jQuery code is actually doing any loops or not.

Comment: Don't prefer jquery code inside Angular. If you still want to. Wrap the code block inside setTimeout(()=>{}, 500);

Comment: Great @ADyson , you have found the problem jQuery runs before Angular (that uses http request) !

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya, your solution works fine ! Do you know if there is a "angular way" to do that ?

Comment: see my answer below for Angular version

Comment: re your edit: you can't call .draggable() on a native element, you must wrap it in a jQuery object first, because it's a jQuery method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the angular version code.

```
<p>Interventions en attente</p>
<ul id='external-events'>
     <li #customevents *ngFor="let ticket of ticketList">
        <div class='fc-event'>{{ ticket.message }}</div>  // Doesn't Work !!
     </li>
</ul>
```

**Component:**

```
@ViewChildren('customevents') customevents: QueryList<any>;
ngAfterViewInit() {
   setTimeout(()=>{
   this.customevents.forEach(function (item) {
        // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
        $(item.nativeElement).data('event', {
            title: $.trim($(item.nativeElement).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
            stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
        });
        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(item.nativeElement).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        });

    });
 }, 100);
}
```

Comment: IMO a timeout is unreliable - it might, in some situations, time out before the AJAX HTTP request mentioned by OP. Adding a callback which waits for the completion of the HTTP request would be much more robust.

Comment: Added timeout to wait until DOM is rendered and its available in ngAfterViewInit life cycle. You can remove here in this case.

Comment: @Suresh Kumar Ariya : I get following error about item.nativeElement.draggable : "ERROR TypeError: item.nativeElement.draggable is not a function"

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya "Added timeout to wait until DOM is rendered" but the issue here is waiting for a separate HTTP request (i.e. AJAX request), this is nothing to do with the initial DOM render

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya and you can't call .draggable() on a native element, you must wrap it in a jQuery object first, because it's a jQuery method. https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: Agree @Adyson. initially he haven't added HTTP request code. seems like it updated now.

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya it was mentioned in the comments a few minutes before you posted your answer. But either way, a timeout is not a good solution for waiting for either an AJAX request, or a DOM render. In either case there is a risk of completing the timeout first, and in either case there are better, _well-known_ methods for _reliably_ waiting for those things to happen.

Comment: Updated the .draggable() with angular way+jquery. Haven't tested it.

Comment: you still aren't setting the "event" data-attribute correctly though - you'll set an attribute called "event"...the original code in the question will set a property called "data-event". This is required for the feature to work correctly with fullCalendar.

Comment: OK, This the result : If I use setTimeOut in ngAfterViewInit, it works. If I move the code inside http method, it doesn't work. (see update 2 in original POST)